# How to choose bInterval in USB Audio 2.0 Standard AS Isochronous Audio Data Endpoint Descriptor?

Tags: audio, usb, usb-descriptor

I am implementing an USB audio input device (STM32 with two microphones), following the *Universal Serial Bus Device Class Definition for Audio Devices, Release 2.0*.

I want to use USB High Speed, not Full Speed. The Standard AS Isochronous Audio Data Endpoint Descriptor has the field *bInterval*.

How should I choose the value for *bInterval*? Can I use a value of 0x01 (interval of 125us) or should I use an interval of 1ms (0x04, which would be the same interval as in Full Speed)? Does a shorter interval has advantages for the amount of samples that can be transferred (later I would like to use up to 16 microphones)?

Comment: «I want the to use USB High Speed» needs one more word!

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Gra. What do you mean with "one more word?" Do you mean USB 2.0? I want to use High-Speed (480 Mbits/s), not Full-Speed (12 Mbits/s), not Low-Speed (1.5 Mbits/s) and not SuperSpeed (5 Gbits/s). What else can I specify?

Comment: In «I want the to use…» there may need a word: «I want the XXX to use…».

Comment: :P Ups, your are right, sorry! Thank you @Gra